# Gigya SDK - Android 3.1 SDK - App crash

Tags: java, android, gigya

If for some reason there's no Internet connection or the request fails, the app crashes when calling:

```
GSAPI.getInstance().initialize(this, GIGYA_API_KEY);
```

The question is: is there someway to catch the Exception? (java.net.SocketTimeoutException and java.util.ConcurrentModificationException)

Trace:

```
08-19 17:53:22.971    2062-2062/************ E/GSAPI﹕ Unable to load config from server:*********** GSResponse Log ***********
    apiKey: ************
    userKey: apiMethod: getSDKConfig
    params: {"enabledProviders":"","ucid":"************","sdk":"android_3.1","format":"json","targetEnv":"mobile","apiKey":"************","include":"permissions"}
    useHTTPS: false
    sdk: android_3.1
    post_data: apiKey=************&enabledProviders=&format=json&httpStatusCodes=false&include=permissions&sdk=android_3.1&targetEnv=mobile&ucid=************&
    url: http://socialize.us1.gigya.com/socialize.getSDKConfig
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to socialize.us1.gigya.com/23.12.180.171 (port 80) after 5000ms
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:159)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:131)
            at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:101)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
            at com.gigya.socialize.GSRequest.sendRequest(Unknown Source)
            at com.gigya.socialize.GSRequest.send(Unknown Source)
            at ************.GSAsyncRequest$GSRequestTask.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
            at ************.GSAsyncRequest$GSRequestTask.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-19 17:53:22.971    2062-2062/************ D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-19 17:53:22.981    2062-2062/************ W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0d6db20)
08-19 17:53:26.011    2062-2062/************ E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ************, PID: 2062
    java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
            at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:806)
            at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:833)
            at com.gigya.socialize.android.login.LoginProviderFactory.validatePermissions(Unknown Source)
            at com.gigya.socialize.android.GSAPI$10.onGSResponse(Unknown Source)
            at com.gigya.socialize.android.GSAsyncRequest$1.onGSResponse(Unknown Source)
            at com.gigya.socialize.android.GSAsyncRequest$GSRequestTask.onPostExecute(Unknown Source)
            at com.gigya.socialize.android.GSAsyncRequest$GSRequestTask.onPostExecute(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gigya has a bug fix for this planned in an upcoming patch.  While you wait for the patch to correct this error, you can patch the Gigya mobile SDK yourself, by [downloading it](http://wikifiles.gigya.com/SDKs/Android/GigyaSDK-3.1.zip), and making the changes below, and recompiling:

**./main/java/com/gigya/socialize/android/login/LoginProviderFactory.java**

---

*After*

```
import java.util.Hashmap;
```

*Add*

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
```

---

*Replace*

```
private HashMap<String, LoginProvider> providers = new HashMap<String, LoginProvider>();
```

*With*

```
private ConcurrentHashMap<String, LoginProvider> providers = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, LoginProvider>();
```

---

*Replace*

```
public HashMap<String, LoginProvider> getLoginProviders() {
    return providers;
}
```

*With*

```
public HashMap<String, LoginProvider> getLoginProviders() {
    return new HashMap<String, LoginProvider>(providers);
}
```

---

Comment: do you have a link for the Gigya bug?

Comment: Seems bug is still there in 3.1.1, any idea if 3.1.2 fixes this?